# what more can I say using Sturm's comparison theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, average, sturm-liouville

Can I use Sturm's comparison theorem to say something about the average?

Let $f(t)$ be a continuous function such that $\lim_{t \to \infty } f(t) = \infty$. Let us consider the following function

$$ \ddot{x}(t) + t^2 x(t) = 0. $$

Let $C$ be a constant. Then, we can find $T$ such that $C^2 < t^2$ for all $t > T$. By Sturm's comparison theorem, exist $t^*$ in $(\frac{2\pi k}{C},\frac{2\pi (k+1)}{C})$ such that $x(t^*) = 0$ for every $k$ big enough.

Can we concluded the following?

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) =0 $$

or

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t s x(s) ds =0 $$

Comment: your integration is wrong.

Comment: Right, this was nonsense.